# Cant get remote access to PostgreSQL

Tags: debian, postgresql

There is PostgreSQL 9.2 in Debian. My `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf` file contains:

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.0, 212.49.109.137'
password_encryption = on
```

'212.49.109.137' is the IP of the computer running PostgreSQL.

`/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf` contains:

```
host    all         all        85.12.201.202         255.255.255.0  md5
```

85.12.201.202 is the IP address of the client that tries to connect. I try to connect using:

```
psql -h 212.49.109.137 -U postgres -d postgis_template
```

And get error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Timeout
Is the server running on host "212.49.109.137" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In `netstat -pln` i see:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.0:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5127/postgres
```

Comment: can you connect locally?

Comment: @Alexandre Alves: Yeah i can connect localy.

Comment: Where i can look at whats going wrong?

Comment: @KliverMax Have you restarted postgresql? Another guess, given that you have a timeout it is likely that your firewall is configured to drop packets.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Our Admin says that he open 5432 port. And yeah i restart and stop/start postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

Checklist:

- Have you reloaded/restarted the server after configuration changes?
- Is the firewall configured to pass TCP port 5432 from the client?
- Is PostgreSQL actually running on that port? Use `netstat -tnlp | grep :5432` to find out. (run as root to get the program name)
- Is no other rule in `pg_hba.conf` blocking access?
- Are there any errors in your error log?

Now that I am looking at your specific configuration, it looks like you have specified the subnet mask in a wrong way. Try this instead:

```
host    all     all     85.12.201.202/32    md5
```

I diverged from your mask 255.255.255.0 because that allows everyone in the `85.12.201.` network to connect.

Comment: 1. i do stop/start after each config changes 2. Only i can do it belive to admin that he says that open 5432 port 3. i do command and get `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.0:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4864/postgres ` 4. How blocing rules looks like? 5. in var/logs/postgresql/postgresql-9.2.log i see only start and stop lanes.

Comment: @KliverMax If there is a rule before your `host` line stating `host all all 0/0 reject` for example, then all external traffic is blocked. Are you sure that port 5432 has is open? `nmap 212.49.109.137 -p 5432` suggests otherwise.